# Error when updating conda packages: RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda

Tags: linux, python, anaconda, matplotlib

I needed to update the matplotlib when I encountered the following error:

```
conda update matplotlib
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/gpu-server/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - matplotlib


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  libopenblas        pkgs/main/linux-64::libopenblas-0.3.3-h5a2b251_3
  setuptools         pkgs/main/linux-64::setuptools-40.6.3-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  matplotlib                conda-forge::matplotlib-3.0.0-2 --> pkgs/main::matplotlib-3.0.2-py37h5429711_0
  numpy              conda-forge::numpy-1.15.1-py36_blas_o~ --> pkgs/main::numpy-1.15.4-py37h99e49ec_0
  numpy-base                          1.15.3-py36h81de0dd_0 --> 1.15.4-py37h2f8d375_0
  pyparsing          conda-forge/noarch::pyparsing-2.2.2-p~ --> pkgs/main/linux-64::pyparsing-2.3.1-py37_0
  python                                   3.6.8-h0371630_0 --> 3.7.2-h0371630_0
  pytz                 conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2018.6-py_0 --> pkgs/main/linux-64::pytz-2018.9-py37_0
  six                     conda-forge::six-1.11.0-py36_1001 --> pkgs/main::six-1.12.0-py37_0
  wheel                    conda-forge::wheel-0.32.2-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::wheel-0.32.3-py37_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            conda-forge::certifi-2018.11.29-py36_~ --> pkgs/main::certifi-2018.11.29-py37_0
  cycler             conda-forge/noarch::cycler-0.10.0-py_1 --> pkgs/main/linux-64::cycler-0.10.0-py37_0
  kiwisolver         conda-forge::kiwisolver-1.0.1-py36h2d~ --> pkgs/main::kiwisolver-1.0.1-py37hf484d3e_0
  pip                       conda-forge::pip-18.1-py36_1000 --> pkgs/main::pip-18.1-py37_0
  python-dateutil    conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2~ --> pkgs/main/linux-64::python-dateutil-2.7.5-py37_0
  sip                conda-forge::sip-4.19.8-py36hfc679d8_0 --> pkgs/main::sip-4.19.8-py37hf484d3e_0
  tornado            conda-forge::tornado-5.1.1-py36h470a2~ --> pkgs/main::tornado-5.1.1-py37h7b6447c_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  pyqt                                 5.9.2-py36h05f1152_2 --> 5.9.2-py37h05f1152_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

After that I tried updating all conda packages, uninstalling matplotlib, installing setuptools with conda and I always get the same error:

```
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

It seems like anything to do with conda's install/update/remove functionality leads to this error. 
Then I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the setuptools with pip. Re-installation worked but the `RemoveError` persisted. I have no more clue of what is going on below is my `conda list` output and `conda env list` .I have also tried switching from the base environment but the error was still there.

conda list:

```
(base) gpu-server@gpuserver:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/gpu-server/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py36_0  
absl-py                   0.6.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    conda-forge
algopy                    0.5.7                    pypi_0    pypi
anaconda-client           1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
anaconda-navigator        1.9.2                    py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                      py_1    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.3                      py_1    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py36_1003    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
astroid                   2.0.3                    py36_0    conda-forge
astropy                   3.0.5            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
atomicwrites              1.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     18.2.0                     py_0    conda-forge
automat                   0.7.0                      py_1    conda-forge
babel                     2.6.0                      py_1    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.os              0.1.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                      py_3    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                 py36_1000    conda-forge
bitarray                  0.8.3            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
bkcharts                  0.2                      py36_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.1                    openblas    conda-forge
blaze                     0.11.3                   py36_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
blosc                     1.14.4               hdbcaa40_0  
bokeh                     1.0.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                   py36_0  
boto3                     1.9.32                     py_0    conda-forge
botocore                  1.12.33                    py_0    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36h7eb728f_1    conda-forge
bz2file                   0.98                       py_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5  
c-ares                    1.15.0               h470a237_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2018.12.5                     0  
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2018.11.29            py36_1000    conda-forge
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h5e8e0c9_1    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py36_1003    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               0.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
clyent                    1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
conda                     4.6.2                    py36_0  
conda-build               3.16.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
constantly                15.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
contextlib2               0.5.5                      py_2    conda-forge
cryptography              2.4.2            py36h1ba5d50_0  
cryptography-vectors      2.3.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge
cuda92                    1.0                           0    pytorch
cudatoolkit               9.0                  h13b8566_0  
cudnn                     7.1.2                 cuda9.0_0  
curl                      7.63.0            hbc83047_1000  
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cython                    0.29             py36hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
dash                      0.35.1                   pypi_0    pypi
dash-core-components      0.42.1                   pypi_0    pypi
dash-html-components      0.13.4                   pypi_0    pypi
dash-renderer             0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dash-table                3.1.11                   pypi_0    pypi
dask                      0.20.0                     py_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 0.20.0                     py_0    conda-forge
datashape                 0.5.4                    py36_0    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.2               h714fa37_1  
decorator                 4.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
distributed               1.24.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
docutils                  0.14                  py36_1001    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.2.3                 py36_1002    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
flask                     1.0.2                      py_2    conda-forge
flask-compress            1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-cors                3.0.6                      py_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0  
gast                      0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
gensim                    3.5.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    1.3.6            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0  
glob2                     0.6                        py_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36hb705a9b_2    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.12               h23475e2_2  
greenlet                  0.4.13                   py36_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.16.1           py36hf8bcb03_1  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
h5py                      2.8.0            py36h7eb728f_3    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
html5lib                  1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
hyperlink                 17.3.1                     py_0    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.7                   py36_1002    conda-forge
imageio                   2.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        0.6                      py36_0    conda-forge
incremental               17.5.0                     py_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.0                      118  
ipykernel                 5.1.0              pyh24bf2e0_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.1.1           py36h24bf2e0_1000    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.4                 py36_1000    conda-forge
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.13.1                py36_1000    conda-forge
jeepney                   0.4                        py_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10                       py_1    conda-forge
jmespath                  0.9.3                      py_1    conda-forge
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
jsonschema                2.6.0                 py36_1002    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.3                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py36_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                     py_2    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
keyring                   16.0.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h2d50403_2    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.1               h173b8e3_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5  
libcurl                   7.63.0            h20c2e04_1000  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libiconv                  1.15                 h470a237_3    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.36               hbc83047_0  
libprotobuf               3.6.1                hd28b015_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h1ba5d50_4  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_2  
libtool                   2.4.6                h544aabb_3  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.8                h26e45fe_1  
libxslt                   1.1.32               h1312cb7_0  
llvmlite                  0.25.0           py36hd28b015_1    conda-forge
locket                    0.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
lxml                      4.2.5            py36hc9114bc_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
markdown                  2.6.11                     py_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.0              py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.0.0                         2    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.0.0            py36hc039c98_2    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.0                      118  
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h90e4bf4_5  
mkl_fft                   1.0.6                    py36_0    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
more-itertools            4.3.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3  
mpmath                    1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36h2d50403_3    conda-forge
multipledispatch          0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0  
nbconvert                 5.4.0                         1    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
nccl                      1.3.5                 cuda9.0_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0  
networkx                  2.2                        py_1    conda-forge
ninja                     1.8.2                h2d50403_1    conda-forge
nltk                      3.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
nose                      1.3.7                 py36_1002    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
numba                     0.40.0           py36hf8a1672_0    conda-forge
numdifftools              0.9.20                   pypi_0    pypi
numexpr                   2.6.8            py36hf8a1672_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.15.1          py36_blas_openblashd3ea46f_0    conda-forge
numpy-base                1.15.3           py36h81de0dd_0  
numpydoc                  0.8.0                      py_1    conda-forge
oauthlib                  2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
odo                       0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
openblas                  0.2.20                        8    conda-forge
openpyxl                  2.5.9                      py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1a               h7b6447c_0  
packaging                 18.0                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.23.4           py36hf8a1672_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hea2e7c5_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0  
parso                     0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
partd                     0.3.9                      py_0    conda-forge
patchelf                  0.9                  hf484d3e_2  
path.py                   11.5.0                     py_0    conda-forge
pathlib2                  2.3.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.42                 h439df22_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.6.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pillow                    5.3.0            py36h34e0f95_0  
pip                       18.1                  py36_1000    conda-forge
pixman                    0.34.0               hceecf20_3  
pkginfo                   1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
plotly                    3.6.0                    py36_0    plotly
pluggy                    0.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.6                      py_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.6.1            py36hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
psutil                    5.4.7            py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
py                        1.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.4                      py_1    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                       py_0    conda-forge
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36h470a237_2    conda-forge
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py36h1ba5d50_0  
pyflakes                  2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyflux                    0.4.15                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pyhamcrest                1.9.0                      py_2    conda-forge
pyjwt                     1.6.4                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.1.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
pyodbc                    4.0.24           py36hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h05f1152_2  
pysocks                   1.6.8                 py36_1002    conda-forge
pytables                  3.4.4            py36h4f72b40_1    conda-forge
pytest                    3.9.3                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pytest-arraydiff          0.2                        py_0    conda-forge
pytest-astropy            0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-remotedata         0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python                    3.6.8                h0371630_0  
python-crfsuite           0.9.6            py36h2d50403_0    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.7.5                      py_0    conda-forge
python-libarchive-c       2.8                   py36_1004    conda-forge
pytorch                   0.4.1            py36ha74772b_0  
pytz                      2018.6                     py_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.0.1            py36h7eb728f_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    3.13             py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py36hae99301_1    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.5.2              pyh8a2030e_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.5.2              pyh8a2030e_0    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
requests                  2.20.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
retrying                  1.3.3                    py36_2  
rope                      0.10.7                     py_1    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.71          py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
s3transfer                0.1.13                py36_1001    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.14.1           py36hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.20.0           py36h4989274_1  
scipy                     1.1.0           py36_blas_openblash7943236_201    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
secretstorage             3.1.0                 py36_1001    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
service_identity          17.0.0                     py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                40.7.3                   pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                      py_1    conda-forge
singledispatch            3.4.0.3               py36_1000    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8           py36hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
six                       1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
smart_open                1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                      py_1    conda-forge
sortedcollections         1.0.1                      py_1    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    1.8.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py36_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                      py_1    conda-forge
spyder                    3.2.8                    py36_0    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.2.12           py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.26.0               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h7eb728f_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.3                   py36_1000    conda-forge
tblib                     1.3.2                      py_1    conda-forge
tensorboard               1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.10.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.1                 py36_1001    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
torchfile                 0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
torchvision               0.2.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge
tornado                   5.1.1            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.28.1                     py_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
twisted                   18.9.0           py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
twython                   3.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
typed-ast                 1.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
unicodecsv                0.14.1                     py_1    conda-forge
unidecode                 1.0.23                   py36_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.23                  py36_1001    conda-forge
visdom                    0.1.8.5                       0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websocket-client          0.54.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.14.1                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.32.2                   py36_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
xlsxwriter                1.1.2                      py_0    conda-forge
xlwt                      1.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
zeromq                    4.2.5                hf484d3e_1  
zict                      0.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2  
zope                      1.0                      py36_1  
zope.interface            4.6.0            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

conda env list:

```
(base) gpu-server@gpuserver:~$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/gpu-server/anaconda3
```

Any help or insight about what could be wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

I think [this issue in github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8149) may be related. [This response](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8149#issuecomment-477799562) mentions doing an update of conda using the `force` flag, which seemed to also work for users who reported that a normal update without the flag didn't work:

```
conda update --force conda
```

Comment: I got the same error when trying this. I ended up reinstalling everything and then the issues were gone. Thanks for the tip though, that issue seems really similar and the solution might work for someone else.

Comment: No joy for me.  Still same error.

Comment: Also note `--force` will be deprecated in the future; `--force-reinstall` is the primary replacement: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this made things worse for me as I'm now facing this issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7931

Comment: the solution posted in GH didn't work for me, I had to bootstrap setuptools from conda-forge by using microconda. See [more detail in my GH comment on that issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8149#issuecomment-1227794991)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why the above answer had negative rating.

I had conda running for some time ... tonight I updated, and then resulted in every conda action resulting in:

```
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

The only thing that actually worked was

```
conda install -c anaconda setuptools
```

After which sanity was restored. In between correction attempts I tried to create a new environment which always failed with the same error. After the fix above, I found that the desired environment did not exist in 'conda env list' but it refused to create it giving an error that it already existed. I needed to go into my ~/miniconda3/envs directory where I found the offending directory, deleted it, and was able to create a desired.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

setuptools is not installed by conda but pip, so you need to uninstall setuptools by pip

```
pip uninstall setuptools
```

and reinstall it though conda:

```
conda install setuptools
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall the dependency:

`conda install -c anaconda setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

This was the only thing that worked for me, when using **miniconda** in *pwsh* on a Win8 machine.

```bsh
# Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.
conda clean -a -vv

conda deactivate
conda update -y -n base -c defaults conda --force
conda activate
conda update -y --force conda
pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: Old post, but just to say this is the only solution that worked for me when I encountered this problem just now.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the potentially obvious, which is the only solution that worked for me (I tried all of the above to no avail):

```
conda update -n base conda setuptools
```

Essentially, tell conda to not remove setuptools if it's so precious.

Note: It's possible that if setuptools was installed before using pip instead of conda, you need to apply easton's solution before this one.